# Dynamically logging PLSql statements in a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have bunch of plsql which has dynamic queries ( ie queries are framed as string and executed with immediate execute function). I want to find the dependent tables and columns for a plsql. I am planning to achieve by GSQL parser. I tried the plsql file as it is, because of dynamic queries, I am not able to get the dependency information. The alternate way is collecting the list of SQL statements executed during the plsql run. How to get sql statement for a plsql and store it a table with unit name mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need execute the sql you have saved with execute immediate;
you will get all sql in below oracle view

```
select * from v$sql;
select * from dba_hist_sqltext;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Basically Application doesn't have dba access, Is there any way we can achieve through triggers on Package , procedure ( including nested) or User Session ?